# Phonegap SQLite 3

Tags: node.js, cordova, angularjs, appjs

I need a way to use SQLite 3 without a quota with Phonegap. I have looked at several plugins but they lack good documentation and none of them say they work with Phonegap 2.0 (1.5+ is touted on most of the plugins).

Furthermore, I don't want to have to set a quota. I need to be able to store gigs of information if necessary in the application. Does anyone know of a good framework like Phonegap? Everything needs to be 100% HTML/CSS/JS.

Right now our product is running an AngularJS front-end with a node.js backend on the server and on our AppJS deployment (native on the desktop). We need an equivalent for mobile devices, but I am afraid that Phonegap may be a mistake. Database access is really the most important piece of the puzzle, more than code reuse and portability. We want to be able to port the same front end across every platform without having to write any code.

Comment: If you're looking to store gigs of data, would it more reasonable to have the database on a server rather than on the device? Gigs seems to me to be a very large scale for mobile device. Unless they will be frequently using large chunks of that data you may want to offload it to a place better suited to handle the size of your database.

Comment: The business requirements of the software stipulate a need for offline access.  I am currently looking at a phonegap plugin, but whether or not it will work is anyone's guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, nothing currently exists which fits your requirements of storing "gigs of information." This is because browsers are limited to 5-10mb of information (see http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#disk-space), and that is what PhoneGap is.

To solve this problem you would have to write a plugin for each device. While they would share the same interface, the underlying code would be different.

Comment: The specification only recommends a limitation of about that size. It maybe possible that the browser PhoneGap uses allows for larger data stores. I don't have a reference to show what that possible limit actually is. Though I do agree with you that a plugin (or completely native apps) will probably be the best option to offer the gigs of data store needed.

Answer (score 0):

There was a solution that worked a year or two ago, when installing the phone gap app include a 50 meg sqlite database (can be dummy data), you
might get away with smaller, but the file should be bigger than the quota. By breaking the quota during install it then is possible to write as much data as you want, even if you then remove the original data and come under the quota. Somehow this prevents os from applying the quota.
I know this worked before but have not tested on the latests android releases.